# Xamarin.Forms error: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2b8000000a3 in tid 24638 (inphone.xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, linphone

I am implementing Linphone in my Xamarin application. I am able to do call properly in my Linphone xamarin app. But when I try to do recording I get the following exception:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr
> 0x2b8000000a3 in tid 24638 (inphone.xamarin), pid 24638
> (inphone.xamarin)

This exception happens after the execution of following code

```
public void StartRecording()
        {
            try
            {
                linphone_call_start_recording(nativePtr);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
```

The code for linphone_call_start_recording is

```
[DllImport(LinphoneWrapper.LIB_NAME)]
        static extern void linphone_call_start_recording(IntPtr thiz);
```

I tried lots of ways like running that method in main thread and deleting bin and obj. But none of them helped me. I have no clue how to fix this any suggestions?

Comment: you can add some breakpoints inside  linphone_call_start_recording to see where goes wrong

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT I tried that aswell. When I do step into code linphone_call_start_recording the app is crashing.

Comment: you could post  the code about the method caused the crash

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT Yeah I have posted the code for that method as well.

Comment: did you add the required permissions in your project Info.plist?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT is it required because I haven't checked the iOS part yet. I'm currently facing this issue for android and for android I have given the required permission in android manifest.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT Also I can see NSMicrophoneUsageDescription in info.plist. So I think the permission is there for recording in iOS aswell.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3112